# How to get and submit the selected item(s) in shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How to get and submit the selected item(s) in  shopping cart?

Below is my demo,
there are 2 questions:
1、At present,I can only get one item manually,how to get all the selected item(s)?
2、If nothing was selected,I want the button "submit" to be disable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/css/tether-theme-basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="goodsTable">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAll">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>Select All
                </label>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xs-5">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-4">Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_100" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Apple</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_100" value="1000"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_101" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Pear</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_101" value="1200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_102" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Peach</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_102" value="1500"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Select all
    $("#selectAll").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        }
    });

    $(".checkboxSelection").change(function () {
        var allSelected = true;
        $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
            if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#selectAll").prop('checked', false);
                allSelected = false;
            }
        });
        if (allSelected)
            $("#selectAll").prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>


<script>
    //Get the value and submit
    $(function () {
        //Below is getting one of the items,how to get all the selected item(s) ?
        var data = {
            "name": $("#goods_100").val(),
            "number": $("#number_100").val()
        };

        //ajax submit
        $(document).on('submit', '#goodsTable', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#submit").addClass('disabled');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ url('/goods/') }}",
                        cache: false,
                        data: data,
                        dataType: "json"
                    })
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        window.location.href = "/goods/success";
                    })
                    .fail(function (textStatus) {
                        $("#submit").removeClass('disabled');
                        alert('Fail,try again');
                    });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Every one of your checkboxes have the same name, so what's happening is:

`domainList = on`
`domainList = on`
`domainList = on`
`domainList = on`

And only the last one gets sent. You need to add `[]` to the name to make it an array.

`domainList[] = on`
`domainList[] = on`
`domainList[] = on`
`domainList[] = on`

That will give the Laravel controller an array instead of just one.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="domainList[]" id="goods_102" class="checkboxSelection">
```

But, you're using these are checkboxes. They have a default value of "on" and only show up in form data when checked. You should definitely add a `value` to it that represents the item's database row.

For instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="domainList[]" id="goods_102" class="checkboxSelection" value="stackoverflow.com" >
```

That would return an array of strings

`domainList[] = stackoverflow.com`
`domainList[] = stackexchange.com`
`domainList[] = serverfault.com`

Comment: Thanks! and the javascript code:```var data = {
            "name": $("#goods_100").val(),
            "number": $("#number_100").val()
        };```How to write here?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Put your table in a `<form id="myform">`, and then set `var data = $("#myForm").serialize();` and jQuery does the rest.

Comment: I want to submit the selected items only,not all. before sumitting,the user must select the item(s) .

Comment: Unselected checkboxes do not get submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Update your script with below for your second question:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($(".table tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
 {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled",false);
 }
 else
 {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
 }

    //Select all
    $("#selectAll").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });
  $('#submit').attr("disabled",false);
        }
        else {
            $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
  $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });

    $(".checkboxSelection").change(function () {
        var allSelected = true;
        $(".checkboxSelection").each(function () {
            if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#selectAll").prop('checked', false);
                allSelected = false;
            }
        });
        if (allSelected)
     {
            $("#selectAll").prop('checked', true);
     }
     if($(".table tr input[type='checkbox']:checked").length < 1)
     {
    $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
     }
     else
     {
     $('#submit').attr("disabled",false);
     }
    });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/css/tether-theme-basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="goodsTable">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAll">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>Select All
                </label>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xs-5">Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-4">Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_100" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Apple</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_100" value="1000"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_101" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Pear</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_101" value="1200"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" id="goods_102" class="checkboxSelection">
                    <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-5">Peach</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_102" value="1500"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks,it's ok but,  when opening, nothing has been done,it's enabled.